# String replace all special characters in the end

Tags: java, regex, string

Am very poor in regex, so please bear with me.

I have strings `LQiW0/QIDAQAB/`  and  `LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB/`.

I'm trying to remove the last forward slash.

Tried   `str= str.replaceAll("\\/","");`

I tried replace all  but  it replaces all forward slashes.. and the thing is, I want to **replace if it is at last position**

Comment: [Here's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) a good regex tutorial.

Comment: No need for the backslash before the `/`, a `/` is nothing special in a regex

Answer (score 14):

Try following code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\/$", "");
```

`$` means end of line (in this case, end of string).

Comment: Also note that replaceFirst("\\/$", "") is equivalent.

Comment: `$` does not mean end of line but end of _input_. That is not quite the same thing.

Comment: @fge, [In the multiline mode, `$` means end of line.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE)

Comment: @fge, I wrote `in this case, end of string` in my answer. If that was not clear, could you edit my answer? (I'm not good at English writing.)

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need regex? A simple `substring` will do the job:

```
str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

But, if you want to replace the forward slash only if it is the end of the string, then `replaceAll` would be good there.

But you can also use this (This might not be more readable compared to `replaceAll`):

```
str = str.endsWith("/") ? str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) : str;
```

Comment: What if at last some character is there ??

Comment: @Baadshah. Do you want to keep everything after that too? You mean you just want to remove the last `/`?

Answer (score 3):

It's better not to use regex replacements for these trivial operations. People tend to use regular expressions all the time even when they are not needed. Also, regular expressions can be very straight forward but get ugly pretty fast when you need to cover some side cases. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions

In your case there's a good tool for the job.

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`

```
StringUtils.stripEnd("LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB/", "/")   = "LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB"
StringUtils.stripEnd("LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB///", "/")   = "LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB"

StringUtils.stripStart("///LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB/", "/")   = "LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB/"
StringUtils.stripStart("///LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB///", "/")   = "LQiW0/QIDAQAdfB///"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replaceAll(@"\/(?=\n)", "");
```

This should match a forward slash that is followed by a new line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have strings like `LQiW0/QIDAQAB/Sdf4s` and you want to remove the last `/` to obtain `LQiW0/QIDAQABSdf4s`, then this will work.

```
str = str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf('/'))+str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

It will also work for cases with the last character `/`.